# Why is my regex whitelist not catching brackets?

Tags: regex, vbscript

My regex whitelist is testing against query parameters. When I pass a parameter of `<img>`, it's not catching the `<` or `>`

```
<%
Function FoundSpecialChar(strInput)
   On Error Resume Next 
    Dim objRegExp
    Set objRegExp = New Regexp
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True

    objRegExp.Pattern= "^[^-A-Za-z0-9 ]+$"  

    if objRegExp.Test(strInput) then
        FoundSpecialChar= true
        exit function
    end if

    FoundSpecialChar= false

    Set objRegExp = Nothing
End Function
%>
```

Comment: This is vbscript, right?  If it is please tag it as such.

Comment: I hope you're not using regex where you should be using an parser.  Having said that: try a regex  pattern of  `[A-Za-z0-9\<\>]`   I don't have any Microsoft available to test that.

Comment: We are not using a parser for classic asp. Should we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression says:

```
^               # Starting at the beginning of the line,
[^-A-Za-z0-9 ]  # look for anything OTHER than dashes, letters, numbers, or space
+               # one or more times
$               # until the end of the line
```

it will only return true if exactly that happens. So it will match:

```
^@#$
!
<>
```

and others like it.

As soon as you have any letters, numbers, spaces, or the dash anywhere on the line, the regexp will return false.

If you're looking for the presence of those special characters anywhere in the string, you probably need to remove the ^ and $ characters.